# setOnItemSelectedListener in AdapterView Cannot be applied

Tags: android, spinner

I have an activity with 2 Spinners on it.

In the onCreate I declare the Spinners:

```
Spinner spinPhotographer = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinPhotographer);

Spinner spinLocation = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinLocation);
```

I then call a void sub and pass the method the filename of a text file I want to use to populate the Spinners. Each Spinner has it's own text file.

```
populateSpinner("Photographers");

populateSpinner("Locations");
```

Here is the method to read the text files and populate the respective Spinner:

```
private void populateSpinner(String spinnerName) {
    String fileName = ("/sdcard/guestlink/" + spinnerName + ".txt");
    String line;
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Read the lines of text into an ArrayList
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    if (!input.ready()) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            names.add(line);
        }
        input.close();
        //Sort the list alphabetically
        Collections.sort(names);
        //Build the ArrayAdapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, names);

        switch (spinnerName) {
            case "Photographers": {
                //Get handle for spinner object
                Spinner spinPhotographers = (Spinner) 
findViewById(R.id.spinPhotographer);
                //Populate the spinner from the array
                spinPhotographers.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinPhotographers.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            }
            case "Locations":{
                //Get handle for spinner object
                Spinner spinLocations = (Spinner) 
findViewById(R.id.spinLocation);
                //Populate the spinner from the array
                spinLocations.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinLocations.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                spinLocations.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        Utilities.writeToLog(ex.toString(), logFile);
    }


}
```

In the lines spinxxx.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); I get the following error: "setOnItemSelectedListener in AdapterView Cannot be applied" I have tried putting the .setOnItem... in the onCreate area. I just don't get it. The Spinners all populate correctly from the text files.

I also made this method to react to the onItemSelected. My plan is to use arg0 to find out which Spinner selected an item.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long 
arg3) {
    switch(arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.spinPhotographer:
            break;
        case R.id.spinLocation;
            break;
        case R.id.spinGuestidLength:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The activity in which you declare all of the above needs to implement `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`, or, logically, `setOnItemSelectedListener(this)` will fail. `this` refers to the activity.

Comment: I had to declare the class as abstract but the error I was getting is gone. I do not know what abstract does for me but it works.

Comment: No it doesn't. Now it tells me it cannot instantiate the class.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty easy fix; you just have to make sure your `class` implements [`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your `setOnItemSelectedListener` takes in `this`, referring to your current activity. You are probably not implementing the interface `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.`

If you don't wish to implement that interface, you can also try this from your `onCreate`, instead of doing `spinPhotographers.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)`:

```
 spinPhotographers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Object item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //...

        }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `onItemSelected` **listener** add this instead of yours

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
    switch (spinner.getId()) {

case R.id.spinPhotographer:
        break;
case R.id.spinLocation;
        break;
case R.id.spinGuestidLength:
        break;



}
```

Answer (score -1):

implement ur activity

```
implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

inside onCreate add this lines

```
 spinPhotographer .setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
 spinLocation .setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: unnecessary casting is terrible habit ... if `this` would means `Activity` which would be implement given interface than casting is bad ... fx you would remove implementation and your code will still compile but you would get runtime exception ... no I didn't downvote this question as first part should solve the problem